# How can I find the Total Sum when given some specific criteria in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

BUSINESS CASE:

There are two columns in a customer_table, ColumnA contains amount deposited or withdrawn by the customer , ColumnB contains  date of transactions.

The customer is charged 5$ interest every month, which it is only waived off if the customer pays at least $100 and must make this payment at least 3 times a month.

Example:

1. If he deposit $10, $10, $80 in a single month, then doesn't pay a
   $5 interest ( because the customer fulfills the 2 conditions).
2. If he deposits $100, $100 in a single month, then he is been charged a $5 interest ( because payment was done only two times)

**TASK**: Write a query to show the total amount transacted by the customer.

NB: *Amount recorded with a negative sign "-$100" indicates deposit made my customer, otherwise indicates amount withdrawn.*

Please consider this table below:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_table (
    [amount] float,
    [Date]  date);

INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '3/31/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( -50, '4/6/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( -50.50, '4/10/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '12/8/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( -30.50, '3/1/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( -40.50, '5/19/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '10/13/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '4/20/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( -30.50, '5/22/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '7/6/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 60, '12/25/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '8/22/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 86.50, '10/20/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 100.50, '6/17/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( 200, '3/11/2021')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES( -40.50, '5/18/2021')
```

This was the query I wrote, but indeed it is very wrong and I can't seem to figure out a logical way to arrive at the solution.

```
SELECT
CASE when
(SUM(amount) >=-100 )AND (COUNT(amount) >= 3) Then SUM(amount)+ 5
ELSE SUM(amount) END [new_amount]
, COUNT(amount) [count_transaction ],
MONTH(Date) [Month]  from customer_table
GROUP BY MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Postgresql? The above looks more like SQL Server code.

Comment: No customer id column in the customers table?

Comment: You create one table, but inserts into another...

Comment: @jarlh Sorry , I have just modified the question , and yes it is an SQL Server code

Comment: Don't forget to _specify_ the expected result, i.e. [mcve]. Also, homework related questions are expected to show more effort.)

Comment: Then perhaps you should change the tags: remove Postgres, add Sql-Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage common table expressions. First calculate deposit count and deposited amount for each month. Then you can calculate each month's fee and add to that month's total balance.

fiddle is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bfa09891ff1f6c65d1091d4c5df0bdf

```
with deposits as (
  select 
    year([Date]) as y, 
    Month([Date]) as m, 
    sum(amount) as totalpayment, 
    count(amount) as paymentcount
  from customer_table
  where amount < 0
  group by year([Date]), Month([Date])
), balance as (
  select 
    year([Date]) as y, 
    Month([Date]) as m, 
    sum(amount) as amount
  from customer_table
  group by year([Date]), Month([Date])
  union all
  select
    deposits.y as y,
    deposits.m as m,
    case
      when (totalpayment <= -100 and paymentcount >= 3) then 0
      else 5
    end as amount
  from deposits
)
select y, m, sum(amount)
from balance
group by y, m
```

Comment: Thank you @Abudullah. This  solution fixes the problem.